# why would session_set_save_handler not be working PHP 5.2

Tags: php, session

Here's the code, I'm making an educated guess that s`ess_read` gets called when a session var is assigned. It is assigning the value. Is there a way I can test this?

```
 function sess_open($sess_path, $sess_name) {


        return true;
    }

    function sess_close() {
        return true;
    }

    function sess_read($sess_id) {

        echo "TEST";
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT Data FROM sessions WHERE SessionID = '$sess_id';");
        if (!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
            $CurrentTime = time();
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO sessions (SessionID, lastseen) VALUES ('$sess_id', $CurrentTime);") or die(mysql_error());

            return '';
        } else {
            extract(mysql_fetch_array($result), EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'sess');
            mysql_query("UPDATE sessions SET lastseen = $CurrentTime WHERE SessionID = '$sess_id';");
            return $sess_Data;
        }
    }

    function sess_write($sess_id, $data) {


        $CurrentTime = time();
        mysql_query("UPDATE sessions SET Data = '$data', lastseen = $CurrentTime WHERE SessionID = '$sess_id';");
        return true;
    }

    function sess_destroy($sess_id) {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE SessionID = '$sess_id';");
        return true;
    }

    function sess_gc($sess_maxlifetime) {
        $CurrentTime = time();
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE lastseen + $sess_maxlifetime < $CurrentTime;");
        return true;
    }

    session_set_save_handler("sess_open", "sess_close", "sess_read", "sess_write", "sess_destroy", "sess_gc");
    session_start();
    ini_set('session.gc-maxlifetime', 60);
    $_SESSION['foo'] = "bar";
    $_SESSION['baz'] = "wombat";
```

> echo  $_SESSION['baz'];

//^^^^This returns wombat but why isn't the `sess_read` being called?

EDIT

OK solved it by first of all checking `session_get_save_handler` was working using or `die()`

Then set `session_destroy()` before calling it - this solved the problem. The session had already started in an include somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look at your **sess_read** function you can see that it doesn't return the value for a certain key in the **$_SESSION** array that you are asking for, it reads the entire session content.

the read function is called one time when your script starts and write when the script ends

between these two calls $_SESSION is similar to a regular array that stores data with the exception that it is a **superglobal** (you can access it from any scope)